# Using pattern matching and modulus on the command line

Tags: regex, ksh

I'm using a ksh pattern match to filter a list of files in a directory, as below.

```
fn="${file##*[!0-9]}"
if [[ -n $fn && $(( $fn % 2 )) -eq 0 ]]
```

Would it be possible to use the same pattern match and modulus operator on the command line in a `ls` command?

Ultimately I'd like to be able to perform this in a single loop statement.

```
for file in mail.sh*
do
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to answer if you posted more of your example, but I'm going to guess here that you are trying to files that end in even numbers.

```
for file in *[02468]
do
    ...
done
```

Or, if you want to do something more complicated than mod 2, I would use backticks and perl

```
for file in `perl -e 'join(" ",grep /(\d+)/ && $1 % 2 == 0 , glob "file*");'`
do
    ...
done
```

where `$1 % 2 == 0` is your example arithmetic expression. (Honestly, I would write your whole script in perl as well!)

Comment: Exactly.  Thanks.  I am looking for more than just the pattern match though.  I was hoping to use the modulus operator.  Currently I'm using a combination of piping and awk.

Comment: I love using Perl, as well, but I don't have that option.  I ended up doing this: `for file in $(ls $HOME/mail* | awk '{if ($2%2 == 0) print $0}') do`